# Entity in Symfony bundle that is associate with main app entity for a plugin system

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, bundle

I'm trying to create a plug-in system using Symfony and its bundle system. I know bundle must be independent but for my system, I know my bundle will never be used in another context.

I have a doctrine entity called "Mark" and I want to associate an entity from the main application called "Student" so a student can have a mark from my mark plugin.

For the moment, I only have an entity Mark that is really simple and I don't know how to associate a new field to my Student entity

```php
namespace Zenith\QuinzeBundle\Model; 
[...]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MarkRepository::class)]
class Mark
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $comment = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setComment(string $comment): self
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And this is my Student entity (simplified) :

```php
namespace Zenith\Entity;
[...]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: StudentRepository::class)]
class Student
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $firstname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userfieldValues = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
```

How can I associate this two entities that one is in an app and the other in a bundle ?

Comment: I would say, this is not useful, and by design. Your application has a specific set of entities for it to work. Sure, you could define some prototypical entities in bundles, but I would always make an extension in the "local" namespace, where the associations to my local entities would live, since it would be somewhat useless to impose some kind of super-abstract requirement on the bundled entity's association. I would not add the Entity-Annotation to the bundle-class but only to the local class. And after all that, I would just remove the bundle, because I'd find it silly. (I tried it once)

Comment: I understand and this is what I wanted to do before I needed to add/remove features easily. And I want to work with bundles to do this as a plug-in system. I want the user to juste click "Use this plugin", and it will install and the features will be directly available. If you tell me this is not possible with bundle, I could understand... May be I should think about Symfony recipes ?

Comment: A plugin system concerning database entities can get pretty messy. You have to consider that plugins can be installed at any time, and that it will either need to run a migration to handle any database-related needs, or you will have to architect your database in a way that will leave your source entities unmodified, but that they can detect any new entities via the use of intermediate tables. You'll likely need to look into a join column with multiple identifiers (ID and Entity Type), as well as an interface that pluggable entities will need to follow.

Comment: So the best to do is to register every entities in my main app and my plugins will just extends features using this entities ?
I'm going to find a way to use repositories in my bundles.

Comment: Maybe you should read [Keeping your modules independent](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html)?

Comment: Thanks @bechir that's part of the doctrine documentation I never read ! Very helpful !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bechir suggested, I used [this link form Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html) and worked as a charm !

EDIT : As the comment said the part that solve the problem is the use of the ResolveTargetEntityListener class from Doctrine tools. It can permit you to inject an Entity that implements the same interface that is needed.
I created a bundle for contracts and added every interfaces I need for my entities. Then required this contracts bundle in my main app and my bundle then inject my entities into the doctrine metadata to rewrite the association.

In ContractsBundle

```php
namespace Zenith\ContractsBundle;

interface StudentInterface { ... }
```

```php
namespace Zenith\ContractsBundle;

interface MarkInterface { ... }
```

In main Symfony app :

```php
namespace Zenith\Entity;

use Zenith\ContractsBundle\StudentInterface;

class Student implements StudentInterface {

    {...}
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'student', targetEntity: MarkInterface::class)]
    private Collection $marks;

}
```

In bundle :
In main Symfony app :

```php
namespace Zenith\MyBundle\Entity;

use Zenith\ContractsBundle\MarkInterface;

class Mark implements MarkInterface { ... }
```

Then, define the doctrine listener in your services.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single foreign key link table to the student table.
Connecting table:
student | mark | plugin entity
where student is the foreign key to the student entity.
Mark is the identifier of the plug-in assigned to the student, without using any foreign keys.
With this solution, you can add a new student plugin at any time without modifying the student entity.

Comment: This link table can be an entity and then you can easily manage it from the page

Comment: My problem is to use the student entity outside my main app. I think with this solution, I still have the problem ?